# Why GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method generate two type of tokens?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, google-plus-signin

I am integrating google sign in my android app.I am using newly mentioned Google+ signin Api and am able to get user name ,email,profile photo for my app.But when i call the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() with different parameters i get two kind of tokens.One is base64 encoded idToken (I think it is JWT or Json Web Token) but another one generate a token look diffrent and shorter.Why this happen? If i use

```
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" +SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
            String idToken = "";
            try {
                idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
            }
            return idToken;
        }
```

and it returns a id token like this (Values edited)

eyJhbGciwwHHwSUzsss1gFFggdNiIsImtpZCI6ImU5GGGTtjViNTA4ZjI2MjI2ZWVmZDJlNTgwMmQ2MzBlYmU0MGGGZTQ4NGEifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuss9tIiwic3ViIjoiMTEyMzA2OTkwMjA1NDYyMjkzMDExIiwiYXpwIjoiNDU5NTM4MTI1OTIzLXUzNGZ0aTZyOWJnNGM4MDFjZW82MzVhNWVoNTZzLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiggdWWaWwiOiJsZWppbmtyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJhsGTdWQiOiI0NTk1MzgxMjU5MjMtNDZlN3Q3YzNhbmQ3M2VqcThyZWZvZTFzYTIzdm9wOHEuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29GGTrVudC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0MzI2OTc4MTMsImV4cCI6MTQzMjcwMTQxM30.C3gG3ldJ1qaqBSZF8u88UH0ZVDfLL6mRjz2H0IqenJkjz86XUc0bc3m59UduWPR7tNDfzOP2oTcf3-iinyREd4dek9iXeJegrYgJKkKF-UvC2Dsl00GGIeHHhwbgSHb3W2Ev-L-p8_XHMRHPorWb8uunwHddxxZ1ZVurNS1HHFshuJT

But if i am using following code

```
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        LoginActivity.this,
                        mEmail,
                        "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email ");
```

i get a token look like  this 
ya29.gAFseYYXxt2gh3ssEWSHhgdhgDL9EQR4prBQpNRjigRNcgQMPHHFRWiaWpwdshVclC_ZFDVtNodhggHJ8J

Why this happen? My back end server (somebody else is developing) only taking the last type token (wich is short ).? Is this related to OpenID 2.0 deprecation and Migrating to OpenID Connect? The problem is my app again ask user for permission if i chose to generate second type token ! Guys please give a clear idea about this.

Comment: I have a small problem which you have overcome. I see two `Account` classes: `android.accounts.Account` and `import com.google.android.gms.plus.Account`

Which one did you use to instantiate the object `account`?

I do not see any type of `Account` class that accepts two `Strings` in the constructor

Comment: **Edit**

Figured out that it's `android.accounts.Account`